# Manually load into the cache some tableview's cells

Tags: cocoa-touch, caching, xcode4, uitableview

My question is about put into the cache some tableview's cells.
I would put some cells there to make me able to "dequeue" them when I need.

I know that cells go into the cache automatically when you scroll a tableview, but I would make it manually for all cell and not only for those are not displayed anymore because they were scrolled up or down away fron screen.

greetings

Comment: If my answer wasn't helpful, please explain why not or recast your question.

Answer (score 0):

- You can maintain different queues by using different cell identifier names.
- With iOS 5 and storyboarding, if a cell's contents are pretty much constant, you can configure it as a static cell.

If what you're trying to do goes beyond that, you'll have to explain in more detail why you want to subvert the cell caching mechanism.